# How to resume nodemon process?

Tags: node.js, nodemon

Here is my scenerio, 
I am developing a nodejs application.
I have deployed the application to our server for testing purposes. I am using nodemon to run the app because it's much more easier.

So my problem is, when I am working from home, because of my network problem,I get disconnected from the server frequently.

So, I won't get any logs from the console. What I am doing now is , after each login, I check for nodejs process,
Find the processes, kill it and start the app with nodemon again

My question is , is there any way of resuming our nodemon process?

So that we can see the logs right away rather than the approach that I am following now?

Or is this really a very stupid question question?

If there exist any such method, please let me know.

Please help me, I am searching a lot for this , didn't find a solution.

My server is Ubuntu 16 lts

Thanks

Comment: The simple fix is to use pm2 instead of nodemon. Use the `--watch` option to emulate nodemon's auto restart on file changes

Comment: Note: unlike nodemon, pm2 by default hides all console logs. To view log you need to run `pm2 log`. But this means you can "resume" watching logs anytime from any session

Comment: Pm2 is a solution for managing node running scripts. If you still want to use nodemon, then go for **tmux**, since you can simply create another window session and manage your nodemon running script as you would normally do in the terminal.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are two options, one thing I personally use (and this will remove your dependency on nodemon) is to use `screen`. It's included with most Linux distributions and even if you don't have it installed yet, there's a `screen` package in all major Linux distributions.

You create a new screen (for the first time) with `screen -S name` and whenever you get disconnected you can easily reattach yourself to the screen with `screen -R name`. If you need to detach from your screen you can use `Control+A` and `Control+D` following each other.

`screen` is universal and will work for anything you can do in terminal, it also can be used to create multiple screens if that's needed, just supply a different name argument.

The other solution would be to use `tmux`, but it's not as straightforward as `screen`.

Creation of a new `tmux` session uses the following command `tmux new -s name`, then if you need to reattach to a session you will need to use `tmux ls` and then find the number of your session there and reattach to it via `tmux attach-session -t num`.

Detaching can be done with `Control+B` and `Control+D`.

Comment: This is what I'm look for as well.